# Combining sets with a matrix: sagemath

Tags: sage

I hope everyone is doing fine. I try to do some combinations of sets, but I have no clue how. If anyone can point me in any direction, it will be great. Here is the problem:

```
M = FiniteEnumeratedSet({1, 2})
P1 = cartesian_product([M]*2) 
P1 = P.list()
P2 = cartesian_product([M]*4)
P2 = [p for p in P2 if p[0] <= p[1]]
C = P1 + P2 #len(C) total columns
R = P1*3  #len(R) total rows
```

What I would like to do is to construct a matrix where the number of columns represents the set C (16 columns) and the number of rows represents R (12 lines). The rule for each entrance it will be (some function `entries`):

```
if (i,j) in R and [(i,j) in C:
return -1
elif if (i,j) in R and [(i,u,j,v) in C or (u,i,v,j) in C]:
return 1
else:
return 0
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to define the function `entries` that works.
Thank you.

Comment: Asked and answered at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/58191/combining-sets-with-a-matrix/